# How is my MongoDB database secured from overwrite attacks?

Tags: database, mongodb, security, server

I am a beginner React Native developer and am wondering how my MongoDB database (or databases in general) is secured from overwrite attacks. The way I understand is that users (clients) cannot see my code directly, but if they do see part of it (e.g. the server address) then they could write scripts and create actions themselves, overwriting my database. How is this prevented in practice? And, is it possible for clients to do see my code? I know there are 'private servers' in some MMORPGs so surely there must be a way to find out about the secret sauce (i.e. the application)?

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite attacks"?

Answer (score 0):

> if they do see part of it (e.g. the server address) then they could write scripts and create actions themselves, overwriting my database.

If you have basic security setup, they cannot write and read any data from your database.

Firstly, you must use authentication and configure permissions for each user. You also can use firewall for connections.

**Scenario: servers are in the same data center**

If your servers in the same data center, you can connect all servers with an internet protocol. Thus, the hacker/user cannot reach your database from outside since your servers are already communicating between them. (For that situation, you'd connect your database from local ip.)

**Scenario: servers are not in the same data center**

In this situation, you'd configure your firewall and open only specific ip addresses. If you want to make it harder, you can code RESTapi for your project. Thus, you only need to use special tokens for each request by servers.

Generally, MMORPG games are using separated setups for each continent. They basically use local network for communication but of course ,they are using more complex system compared to what I said.